# 405 Method Not Allowed- google-app-engine issue

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine

i dont know why this is happening but i have tried alot but still i m getting the same output in my browser.. 
i m running this code here  i am trying to inherit the handle class instances to my another class.. i am running my code in using google app engine in chrome browser.. whole process is similar as show by udacity instructor else the rot13 code ..

```
  import os
  import codecs
  import webapp2
  import jinja2
  #from check import valid_month
  #from check import valid_year
  #from check import valid_day

   template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'templates')
   jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader =                   jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir),
                            autoescape= True)

  class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    """docstring for Handler"""
    def write(self, *a, **kw):
    self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)

     def render_str(self, template, **params):
          t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
         return t.render(params)

     def render(self,template,**kw):
        self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))

   class Secondhandler(Handler):
      def get(self):
        key = self.request.get_all("name")
        name = ''.join(key)
        new = codecs.encode(name, 'rot13')
        self.render("shopping_list.html", name = new )

 app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
   ('/',Handler)
     ], debug=True)
```

as you can see my second handler is named secondhandler which inherit from its parent class named handler..
but when i view this in my browser it throws an error  , my shopping list.html is as follows

```
        <form>
           <h2>tell us what you like</h2>
           <br>
           <textarea name='name' type='text'>{{name}}</textarea>
           <br>
           <br>
          <button>add</button>
         </form>
```

most important thing is that i dont think tht there is any indentation issue as when i run my code by using the whole get in just main handler it works fine .. 
but still i am unable to use secondhanlder .. heres my code without class secondhandler .. and it prints and works rot13 nicely..

```
  import os
  import codecs
  import webapp2
  import jinja2
  #from check import valid_month
  #from check import valid_year
  #from check import valid_day

   template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'templates')
   jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader =                   jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir),
                            autoescape= True)

  class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    """docstring for Handler"""
    def write(self, *a, **kw):
    self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)

     def render_str(self, template, **params):
          t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
         return t.render(params)

     def render(self,template,**kw):
        self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))

     def get(self):
        key = self.request.get_all("name")
        name = ''.join(key)
        new = codecs.encode(name, 'rot13')
        self.render("shopping_list.html", name = new )



   #class Secondhandler(Handler):


 app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
   ('/',Handler)
     ], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like you've registered `SecondHandler`:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
 ('/',Handler)
   ], debug=True)
```

What happens when you change `Handler` in that block to `SecondHandler` instead?

Comment: ohh srry mymistake .... thks for your response. that was really silly... still thks .. it works fine

Comment: No worries! :) Happens to all of us. You might want to mark this as the answer!